# Storing 2 messages received from 2 publishers in 1 vector

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I would like to compile a ROS node that takes some Pose2D(x,y,theta) information sent by some publisher node and some Float64 value sent by an other publisher node and store it in some vector. I have the code as below.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"                                                                                                                                                 
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>                                                                                                                              
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>                                                                                                                            
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>                                                                                                          
#include <std_msgs/String.h>                                                                                                                                         
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose2D.h>                                                                                                                                    
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                     
using namespace message_filters;                                                                                                                                     
using namespace std_msgs;                                                                                                                                            
using namespace std;                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                     
class EKF_node                                                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                                    
        public:                                                                                                                                                      
                // constructor                                                                                                                                       
                EKF_node()                                                                                                                                           
                        : y(4)                                                                                                                                       
                {                                                                                                                                                    
                        ros::NodeHandle n;                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                     
                        sub_camera = n.subscribe("chatter", 1, &EKF_node::chatterCallback, this);                                                                    
                        sub_imu = n.subscribe("chatter2", 1, &EKF_node::chatterCallback2, this);                                                                     
                }                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                     
                // callback1                                                                                                                                         
                void chatterCallback(const geometry_msgs::Pose2D::ConstPtr& msg)                                                                                     
                {                                                                                                                                                    
                        ROS_INFO(msg->x);                                                                                                                            
                        y[0] = msg->x;                                                                                                                               
                        y[1] = msg->y;                                                                                                                               
                        y[2] = msg->theta;                                                                                                                           
                }                                                                                                                                                    
                // callback2                                                                                                                                         
                void chatterCallback2(const std_msgs::Float64::ConstPtr& msg)                                                                                        
                {                                                                                                                                                    
                        ROS_INFO("I heard from the second chatter: ", msg->data);                                                                                    
                        y[4] = msg->data;                                
                }                                                                                                                                                    
                //private:                                                                                                                                           
                // vector containing the outputs                                                                                                                     
                vector<std_msgs::Float64> y;                                                                                                                         
                ros::Subscriber sub_camera;                                                                                                                          
                ros::Subscriber sub_imu;                                                                                                                             
};                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                     
int main(int argc, char **argv)                                                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                     
        ros::init(argc, argv, "listenerMultipleTopics");                                                                                                             
        EKF_node myNode;                                                                                                                                             
        ros::Rate r(10);                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                     
        while(ros::ok)                                                                                                                                               
        {                                                                                                                                                            
                ros::spinOnce();                                                                                                                                     
                cout << myNode.y[0] << endl << myNode.y[1] << endl << myNode.y[2] << endl << myNode.y[3] << endl;                                                    
                r.sleep();                                                                                                                                           
        }                                                                                                                                                            
        return 0;                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

**Unfortunately, I get some error message as below (ROS doesn't seem to like something about the equalities). Do you know what could possibly go wrong?**

```
/home/alic/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listenerMult.cpp: In member function ‘void EKF_node::chatterCallback(const ConstPtr&)’:
/home/alic/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listenerMult.cpp:32:16: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> > > >::value_type {aka std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >}’ and ‘const _x_type {aka const double}’)
    y[0] = msg->x;
                ^
In file included from /home/alic/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listenerMult.cpp:8:0:
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note: candidate: constexpr std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >& std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >::operator=(const std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&)
 struct Float64_
        ^~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const _x_type {aka const double}’ to ‘const std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&’
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note: candidate: constexpr std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >& std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >::operator=(std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&&)
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const _x_type {aka const double}’ to ‘std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&&’
/home/alic/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listenerMult.cpp:33:16: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> > > >::value_type {aka std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >}’ and ‘const _y_type {aka const double}’)
    y[1] = msg->y;
                ^
In file included from /home/alic/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listenerMult.cpp:8:0:
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note: candidate: constexpr std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >& std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >::operator=(const std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&)
 struct Float64_
        ^~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const _y_type {aka const double}’ to ‘const std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&’
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note: candidate: constexpr std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >& std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >::operator=(std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&&)
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const _y_type {aka const double}’ to ‘std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&&’
/home/alic/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listenerMult.cpp:34:16: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> > > >::value_type {aka std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >}’ and ‘const _theta_type {aka const double}’)
    y[2] = msg->theta;
                ^~~~~
In file included from /home/alic/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listenerMult.cpp:8:0:
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note: candidate: constexpr std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >& std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >::operator=(const std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&)
 struct Float64_
        ^~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const _theta_type {aka const double}’ to ‘const std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&’
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note: candidate: constexpr std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >& std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >::operator=(std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&&)
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const _theta_type {aka const double}’ to ‘std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&&’
/home/alic/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listenerMult.cpp: In member function ‘void EKF_node::chatterCallback2(const ConstPtr&)’:
/home/alic/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listenerMult.cpp:40:16: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> > > >::value_type {aka std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >}’ and ‘const _data_type {aka const double}’)
    y[4] = msg->data;
                ^~~~
In file included from /home/alic/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listenerMult.cpp:8:0:
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note: candidate: constexpr std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >& std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >::operator=(const std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&)
 struct Float64_
        ^~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const _data_type {aka const double}’ to ‘const std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&’
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note: candidate: constexpr std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >& std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >::operator=(std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&&)
/opt/ros/lunar/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const _data_type {aka const double}’ to ‘std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&&’
beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listenerMult.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listenerMult.dir/src/listenerMult.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listenerMult.dir/src/listenerMult.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2339: recipe for target 'beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listenerMult.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listenerMult.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282290/storing-2-messages-received-from-2-publishers-in-1-vector./) by [edamondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33620/edamondo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2018-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-09**:
Can you please repost your code with smaller indentations so that one line of code isn't spanning multiple lines of the question? Also, please use the preformatted text `101010` button for your terminal output.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
@edamondo: can you explain how this is related to #q282259? It seems like almost a duplicate.

Furthermore:

> ROS doesn't seem to like something [..]

nitpick maybe, but this is not about ROS, but C++. The *C++ compiler* is telling you that your C++ source contains errors and it cannot continue.

**Comment by [edamondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33620/edamondo/) on 2018-02-10**:
Hi gvdhoorn,
It i just that when I posted an update on the initial question, Thomas D suggested to put it in a new question, so here I put this in a new question. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem seems to be a simple type mismatch (and thus a C++ issue). You have:

```
vector<std_msgs::Float64> y;
```

and then in one of the callbacks, there is this:

```
y[0] = msg->x;
y[1] = msg->y;
y[2] = msg->theta;
```

According to the documentation on `Pose2D` ([geometry_msgs/Pose2D](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose2D.html)), the `x`, `y` and `theta` fields are of type `float64`, *not* `std_msgs::Float64`.

You cannot assign primitives to objects in this case.

For the second callback: the *message* is a `std_msgs::Float64`, but the *value* (what you are actually interested in) is in a field called `data`, which is of type `float64` again. So that line will also not work.

I recommend you change your vector to take regular `double`s.

See [wiki/msg](http://wiki.ros.org/msg) for how ROS IDL types map to C++ types.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
A friendly suggestion: from your other questions (#q282259 and #q282167) I get the impression that you're having difficulty with the C++ part of your approach. Conceptually you seem to be doing ok. Perhaps it would be beneficial to follow one or two C++ tutorials, to reduce the ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
.. level of 'magic incantations' that this appears to have at the moment.

It should allow you to focus on what you want to do, instead of battling with compiler errors.

**Comment by [edamondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33620/edamondo/) on 2018-02-10**:
Oh, I didn't notice that float64 was not refering to std_msgs::Float64. Thanks, now I know and it works!
Yes, I am following C++ tutorials in parallel.

**Comment by [edamondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33620/edamondo/) on 2018-02-10**:
By the way, would you happen to know why I can't use ctrl+c to stop this node? My understanding was that if I use while(ros::ok), if I hit ctrl+c it will stop the node, but there are still constantly values that pop on my terminal window.